# Inverse Laplace transform Using Convolution theorem .

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

How Can I find the inverse laplace transform of the following ?

$$\overline{C}(\xi ,s)=\frac{s(s^2+w^2_4)(s^2-w_3^2)}{(s^2+w_1^2)(s^2+w_2^2)(s^2+w_2^2)-(s^2-w_3^2)(s^2+w_4^2)(s^2+w_2^2)}$$

Thank you ...

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+Laplace+transform+%28s%28s%5E2%2B%28w_4%29%5E2%29%28s%5E2-%28w_3%29%5E2%29%29%2F%28%28s%5E2%2B%28w_1%29%5E2%29%28s%5E2%2B%28w_2%29%5E2%29%28s%5E2%2B%28w_2%29%5E2%29%2B%28s%5E2-%28w_3%29%5E2%29%28s%5E2%2B%28w_4%29%5E2%29%28s%5E2%2B%28w_2%29%5E2+%29%29&x=0&y=0). Maybe the expression can be simplified if some "nice" relation for the constants is given.